# Weird behaviour of event recievers

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

When I try to implement itemadded or itemadding event receiver and put [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in)

watermarking code below base.ItemAdding(properties) then the event are not getting triggered. As soon as I remove this watermarking code the event gets triggered. I don't understand why?
Any idea why is it behaving this way?

Comment: I assume that you already shipped the iTextSharp Control within the solution packacke and it is installed into the GAC. And also try to increase the Assembly Version. After that you can look in the uls log, there will be more input for debugging purpose. But mostly I think, the ITextSharp assembly was not deployed within the solution package.

Comment: @Sascha I added the reference of itextsharp in my sharepoint project. What do you mean by installing itextsharp into the gac?

Comment: You should install iTextSharp Assemblies on SharePoint servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must include your third party assembly like describded here:

Just include the assembly in the package

[image]

The complete process is described here.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/

Also look into your ULS to identify the error.

Comment: I did the steps in the post but there was no itextsharp DLL coming up after I added the project name. Instead my project's DLL was included